# Regression in R with loops

Tags: r, loops, regression, linear-regression

I need to run a simple regression using Lm() in R. Its simple because I have only one independent variable. However the catch is that I need to test this independent variable for a number of dependents which are columns in a data frame.

So basically I have one common X and numerous Y's for which i need to extract the intercept and slope and store them all in a data frame.

In excel this is possible with the intercept and slope functions and then dragging across columns. I need something in R that would basically do the same, I could of course run separate regressions , but the requirement is that I need to run all of them in one loop and store estimates of intercept and slopes together for each.

Im still learning R and any help on this would be great. Thanks :)

Comment: I feel like there must be a fair number of duplicates or near-dupes of this, but I can't find them at the moment. @Roland's answers are very good, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lmList` function in package `nlme` was designed for this.

Let's use the `iris` dataset as an example:

```
DF <- iris[, 1:4]
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
#5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
#6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4
#...
```

First we have to reshape it. We want `Sepal.Length` as the dependent and the other columns as predictors in this example.

```
library(reshape2)
DF <- melt(DF, id.vars = "Sepal.Length")
#  Sepal.Length    variable value
#1          5.1 Sepal.Width   3.5
#2          4.9 Sepal.Width   3.0
#3          4.7 Sepal.Width   3.2
#4          4.6 Sepal.Width   3.1
#5          5.0 Sepal.Width   3.6
#6          5.4 Sepal.Width   3.9
#...
```

Now we can do the fits.

```
library(nlme)
mods <- lmList(Sepal.Length ~ value | variable, 
               data = DF, pool = FALSE)
```

We can now extract intercept and slope for each model.

```
coef(mods)
#             (Intercept)      value
#Sepal.Width     6.526223 -0.2233611
#Petal.Length    4.306603  0.4089223
#Petal.Width     4.777629  0.8885803
```

And get the usual t-table:

```
summary(mods)
# Call:
#   Model: Sepal.Length ~ value | variable 
# Data: DF 
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept) 
#              Estimate Std. Error  t value      Pr(>|t|)
# Sepal.Width  6.526223 0.47889634 13.62763  6.469702e-28
# Petal.Length 4.306603 0.07838896 54.93890 2.426713e-100
# Petal.Width  4.777629 0.07293476 65.50552 3.340431e-111
#   value 
#                Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
# Sepal.Width  -0.2233611 0.15508093 -1.440287 1.518983e-01
# Petal.Length  0.4089223 0.01889134 21.646019 1.038667e-47
# Petal.Width   0.8885803 0.05137355 17.296454 2.325498e-37
```

Or the R-squared values:

```
summary(mods)$r.squared
#[1] 0.01382265 0.75995465 0.66902769
```

However, if you need something more efficient, you can use package data.table together with `lm`'s workhorse `lm.fit`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)
DF[, setNames(as.list(lm.fit(cbind(1, value), 
                             Sepal.Length)[["coefficients"]]), 
              c("intercept", "slope")), by = variable]
#       variable intercept      slope
#1:  Sepal.Width  6.526223 -0.2233611
#2: Petal.Length  4.306603  0.4089223
#3:  Petal.Width  4.777629  0.8885803
```

And of course the R.squared values of these models are just the squared Pearson correlation coefficients:

```
DF[, .(r.sq = cor(Sepal.Length, value)^2), by = variable]
#       variable       r.sq
#1:  Sepal.Width 0.01382265
#2: Petal.Length 0.75995465
#3:  Petal.Width 0.66902769
```

Comment: This was helpful :) Was wondering whether there is a way to get the R square values for each regression too. The summary(mods) only returns the T and p-values respectively

Comment: `summary(mods)$r.squared ` for the first approach or `DF[, .(r.sq = cor(Sepal.Length, value)^2), by = variable]` for the second approach.